# sortable UI save order without using sort

Tags: jquery

Here is the way how i am getting data and saving it after I am sorting elements:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
        $('#sortable').sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {            
            //var hidden =  $("#hidden").val();
            newOrder = $(this).sortable('serialize');            
        }
    });
});
```

How to get sort data with included new elements if I am adding new elements but not sorting them? so the array in code not updating. Please help!

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: if I could eleborate it by my self, I would not ask for help. The sing is I need to get the same serialized array with new posiition numbers in it without sorting the list. I thought about pushing random number to array while updating data throught ajax, but it is not actually what I need, because the list will be numbered but not positioned.